# How to set my textview to display all elements in my json array

Tags: java, android, json

parsing json and i'm trying to setText a textview to do all elements in my array. Obviously I am doing something wrong here, would appreciate any help.

```
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        try {
            String buildings = getJSON("http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=True");

            //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(buildings);
            JSONArray queryArray = new JSONArray(buildings);
            //queryArray = queryArray.getJSONArray(0);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i=0; i<queryArray.length(); i++) {
                list.add( queryArray.getString(i) );

            }
            String text = list.get(0).toString();
            String arr[] = text.split(" ");
            arr[0] = arr[0].trim();
            for(int i=0;i>queryArray.length();++i)
            {
                tv1.setText(list[i]);
            }
```

Comment: what issue you are getting ?

Comment: Just think about your code for a second.. setText-method does not APPEND the text.

Comment: use  `tv1.append(list.get(i0);` or `tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+list.get(i))`

Comment: And `i > queryArray.length()` doesn't work... it should be `i < queryArray.length()`

Comment: @Raghunandan I think you mean `tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+list.get(i))`...list is a List object

Comment: @CRUSADER hmmm. you are right

Comment: @Raghunandan "The type of the expression must be an array type but is resolved to List<string>

Comment: @user3380292 re-red my comments i have updated. should be `tv1.append(list.get(i))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an infinite loop here ;

```
for(int i=0;i>queryArray.length();++i)
{
    tv1.setText(list[i]);
}
```

Also, the above snippet displays one line from your list on the textview each time the loop is running. It doesn't append the text on the textview. Try to optimize your code a bit, that you can do the task in one loop.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<queryArray.length(); i++) {
    // chain each string, separated with a new line
    sb.append(queryArray.getString(i) + "\n");
}
// display the content on textview
tv1.setText(sb.toString());
```

ref : [StringBuilder - Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: It is not an infinite loop, it will just skip the `for` loop. But yes, that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this dude :) u didnt concat all string just do with this

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            try {
                String buildings = getJSON("http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=True");

                //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(buildings);
                JSONArray queryArray = new JSONArray(buildings);
                //queryArray = queryArray.getJSONArray(0);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i=0; i<queryArray.length(); i++) {
                    list.add( queryArray.getString(i) );

                }

                String finaltext="";
                for(int i=0;i>list.size();i++)
                {
                    finaltext.concat(list.get(i));
                }

                tv1.setText(finaltext.trim());
```